# Error setting text in collection view cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

when I nslog the value after setting it it is NULL, any word why?

```
CustomCollectionVIewCell *cell =[[CustomCollectionVIewCell alloc]init];
NSString *name =[dict valueForKey:@"filterName"];//works
[cell.labelDisplay setText:name];//does not
NSLog(@"name = %@",cell.labelDisplay.text);
cell.isSelected=NO;
[_availableHealthFilters setObject:cell atIndexedSubscript:i];
```

Comment: is your `name` showing correct value?

Comment: I would guess that your name variable is NULL. Try to log that string.

Comment: Where do you allocate/init labelDisplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init your labelDisplay in custom cell.

```
//customColectionCell.h
@property(strong,nonomatic) NSString *labelText;
-(void)setCellLabelText:(NSString *)labelText;
//customCollectionCell.m
-(id)init{
//init cellLabel and addSubView to customCell 

}
//Than set label in custom method
-(void)setCellLabelText:(NSString *)labelText{
_labelText = labelText;
sefl.labelDisplay.text = labelText;
}
```